# Deny password-based SSH login for all users through a Python script

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, sed, sshd

I am writing a Python script to deny password-based SSH login for a remote server (Ubuntu 18.04). I will be running the Python script inside my host system (Windows). Therefore I have already established an SSH connection with the remote host using the paramiko module and initialising the SSH client.

In order to deny password-based SSH login, I should edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and change the line 'PasswordAuthentication yes' to 'PasswordAuthentication no'
Note that my remote system allows passwordless `sudo`. I need to just do this one replace in the `sshd_config` file.

Given below is the command that I tried:

```py
ssh_client.exec_command("sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config")
```

I'm hitting the error: `couldn't open temporary file .sedVg2nV6: Permission Denied`

Has anyone encountered this before?
Is there another way to replace a part of config file other than `sed`? Is `sed` only for `.txt` files?

Comment: The error message means `sed` needs to run as root to create its temporary output file. The error message is just a spurious symptom; the real problem here is that you can't edit system files if you are not `root`. (`sed -i` creates a temporary file behind the scenes, then moves it back on top of the original input file if it succeeds.)

Comment: Part of the beauty of Unix is that basically all config files _are_ text files.

Comment: Thank you so much for that, very new to Unix and hopefully I'll get better soon thanks to this great community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change
`ssh_client.exec_command("sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config")`
to
`ssh_client.exec_command("sudo sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config")` (the sed command will be executed with root permissions).

Comment: The `/g` flag is also completely pointless here, it says to replace all occurrences *on every line* but you only expect one occurrence per line, max.

Comment: Thanks for that. It was a rookie mistake.

Comment: @PraveenMathew no problem !